# i want to write the query for the joining of the three tables and getting the data from the third tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to getting the data from the three tables from one table I want the amount and from the another table I  am getting the loan amount if the loan amount exists in the  table then only it will subtract from the second table or else I want the only second table amount  and it should get  in the single query only

```
select  C.id id,route_number route_number,supervisor supervisor,centre_code centre_code,name name,mobile mobile,agent_name agent_name,bankno bankno,D.date ddate,bankname bankname,C.branch branch,ifsc ifsc,round(sum(D.net),3) amount  
from school_center C, school_daily_data D 
where centre_code = D.centercode and D.date between '2021-01-01' and '2021-01-31' 
join school_loanbillsdata L ON amount = amount - L.installment_amt 
where if exists L.centercode = D.centercode and L.idate between '2021-01-01' and '2021-01-31' 
group by D.centercode;
```

Comment: (1) The query must contain one WHERE clause - so move all conditions to the last WHERE and remove intermediate WHERE. (2) All output columns except one mentioned in GROUP BY must be arguments of some aggregate function.

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.